# Why might IIS not restart a ASP.net worker process (w3wp.exe) when the dlls used in it's execution get updated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

We have several ASP.net WebApplications running on our server.
We replace several of the dlls from within one of them and wait.
We expect that the server will, in due cause, detect the changes to the dlls and restart said worker process.

Normally I'd expect a 2nd worker process to be started up to handle new requests whilst the old one is left to finish processing any that were already underway. At which point, I'd assume that the old worker process would be gracefully ended and things continue as normal.

However I have a Process Explorer instance looking at the instance of W3W.exe which I know to be responsible for the App Pool in question (I have the command-line column present in the grid) and despite replacing it's dlls 3 times today, it still shows a Start Time of midday yesterday. By now that is more than 24 hours ago.

What can possibly be causing the system to ignore changes to it's own dlls like this?

Comment: There is no process change to observe. It is ASP.NET runtime that performs a reload, which is a change in AppDomain level, https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/february/reasons-for-aspnet-application-restarts-on-iis-server/

Comment: IIS will only recycle the application pool when you make change to application pool configuration. Update dll doesn't belong to application pool configuration change so the old worker process will keep loading old dll.